# How to change listbox style for each item to allow word wrap in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I want to each row in listbox can display text with word wrap when its width is set to a fix width and the text is longer than the width.

For example, 'This is a long string.' is displayed as one line, but 'This is a long string.This is a long string.This is a long string.' can be displayed as 3 lines as it is one item in list box.

So the height for each row in list box could be different depending on the context.

how to create a simply style for this case?

Comment: Are you looking to do this in XAML or in the code-behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by modifying the ItemsTemplate

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourItems}">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextProperty}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
           </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

This assumes your viewmodel has a "YourItems" property that is an IEnumerable and that YourObject has a TextProperty property on it that is a string